# How to use font-face in xamarin UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I am working on cross platform app. In webview I want to use @font-face. It is working fine on Android but not working on UWP. My font file is in Assets/Fonts folder and in style sheet I am using the below code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'defont';
    src: url('Assets/Fonts/mher.ttf');
}
```

In Android I was using this:

```
src: url('file:///android_asset/mher.ttf');
```

But when same approach I try in UWP, it is not working.
Please anyone has any idea?

**UPDATE:**

Below is my C# code of using normal WebView. I am getting html content from local html file, replace some placeholders and display new html string to WebView.

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(WebViewPage)).Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Assets.MyTemplate.html");

string templateHtml = "";
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    templateHtml = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

templateHtml = templateHtml.Replace("{pageHeading}", _post.Title);
templateHtml = templateHtml.Replace("{body}", _post.Content);
if (_post.IsFeaturedImageAvailable)
{
    templateHtml = templateHtml.Replace("{imgSrc}", _post.FeaturedImageUrl);
}else
{
    templateHtml = templateHtml.Replace("{imgSrc}", "");
}
templateHtml = templateHtml.Replace("pdfprnt-buttons", "pdfprnt-buttons hide");

htmlSource.Html = templateHtml;
htmlSource.BaseUrl = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
browser.Source = htmlSource;
Content = browser;
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13700561/7462031

Comment: This link is just telling about styling a html page. Style sheet is already working fine and my html page is getting styles from style sheet. The only problem is that it is not getting @font-face.

Comment: Okay then have a look here http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/01/04/a-complete-guide-to-working-with-custom-fonts-in-your-windows-and-windows-phone-app

Comment: This link is for using custom font in xamarin forms control like label etc. I am already using this font on label and it is working fine. The problem is using in WebView on html page using css @fone-face property.

Comment: Did you read it till the end?

Comment: yes brother i go through till end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has special [`Uri Scheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes) within UWP. For for getting the font in the Assets folder, you need use [`ms-appx-web://`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#ms-appx-and-ms-appx-web).  Please try the following  code.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'defont';
    src: url('ms-appx-web:///Assets/Fonts/mher.ttf');
}
```

**Update**

I used [`HybridWebView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/hybridwebview/) that could load local html file directly. Then add the css file in UWP project.

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:10px}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('ms-appx-web:///Assets/hello.ttf')
}

body, p, h1, span {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
}
```

[image]

This is [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/HybridWebView) that you could refer.

Comment: Although I already had tried it but now tried again and is not working. I have tested both ms-appx and ms-appx-web. Both are not working.

Comment: It seems HybridWebview can solve the problem. I have a placeholder in my local html file like {myPlaceHolder} and before displaying to user, I need to replace this place holder with some dynamic html. In my previous approach it was just simple by using C# replace function on html string. How can replace this placeholder before showing html to user?

Comment: Could you share a code sample that I will view the issue quickly ?

Comment: I have updated my question post. In my code I am doing many replacement in html string. But don't know either it is possible in HybridWebView.

Comment: OK, I will check.

Comment: No bother at all.