# how to load custom fonts in webview in xamarin forms uwp project

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, custom-font, xamarin.uwp

Im having problem to load and apply custom fonts in html data loaded into a webview component in a xamarin forms UWP project.Since the fonts doesnt get loaded, the proper font is not applied to the text in the html.

Im creating a xamarin forms application in which i use a webview view to display html data from a book. The data is text from a book and uses some custom fonts like Alvi Nastaleeq to style the text. The fonts are applied in the IOS and Android versions using font-face rule but it doesnt work in UWP.
The fonts are in the Assets/Fonts folder in the UWP project.

I have tried using font-face rule in UWP with correct URI-scheme ms-appx-web:// and it doesnt work.
I have also gone through the suggestion in the following post:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/10/23/about-webview-and-fonts/
and doesnt work either

I have tried loading both .woff and .ttf fonts but it doesnt work.

this is what i have in the header of the html:

```
            // this one was a try for UWP.. not working..
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'Alvi Nastaleeq';
        src: url('ms-appx-web:///Assets/Fonts/Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf');
        } 

             // theese are for IOS and Android and works..
       @font-face { 
        font-family: Alvi Nastaleeq;
        src: url('Fonts/Alvi Nastaleeq.ttf') 
            }
        @font-face { 
        font-family: Aslam;
        src: url('Fonts/Aslam.ttf') 
            }
        @font-face { 
        font-family: Al Qalam Quran Majeed;
        src: url('Fonts/Al Qalam Quran Majeed.ttf') 
            }
        @font-face { 
        font-family: Amiri-Bold;
        src: url('Fonts/Amiri-Bold.ttf') 
            }
   </style>
```

I want to get the fonts applied to the html data loaded into the webview view in the UWP version of my xamarin forms application.

Comment: Please check this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984563/how-to-use-font-face-in-xamarin-uwp/53992740#53992740).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i have already checked this case and already tried it out, doesnt work, thanks anyways.

Comment: Is it local html file?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT the html data is in a file which i load into a variable and then pass it onto the webview

Comment: Could you  share a mini sample that I could test directly ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use font-face in xamarin UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984563/how-to-use-font-face-in-xamarin-uwp)

Answer (score 3):

This was the only way I was able to get it to work:

1. Encode your font, you can use [Font Squirrel's Webfont Generator](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). Select **Expert...** options then under the **CSS options** tick the box for "**Base 64 Encode**". Note if you're unhappy with the result (rendering looks poor), try again and under Expert options select "**Keep Existing**" for the "**Truetype Hinting**".
2. Set your @font-face **src** property equal to the following:

TTF FONTS:

```
url(data:application/font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64,YOUR_BASE64_STRING_HEREE) format('truetype');
```

OPENTYPE FONTS:

```
url(data:font/opentype;charset=utf-8;base64,YOUR_BASE64_STRING_HERE);
```

WOFF FONTS:

```
url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,YOUR_BASE64_STRING_HERE) format(???woff???);
```

Comment: Full disclosure I only tested using TTF and confirmed that to be working. Not 100% sure about .otf/.woff

Comment: Thanks. i have tried this one as well and it didnt work, but i will give it another shot, maybe i forgot something.